# How to combine two form functions without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

## EDIT (using only jQuery)

I changed the code based on the comments so I don't need a form.
I'm not the greatest in coding, but I try. When I use the code below `<div class="td3-title" id="result_in"></div>` doesn't show a number (it's empty).

`<div class="td2">1</div>` will later be a calculation for the percentages, but that's for later.

What I want to achieve is:

- auto calculate the fields
- adding extra fields and the script should be able to calculate the extra fields also (add it to the jQuery-code)
- everything should happen on page (not sending data to a server)

```js
<script>
$("#in1").keyup(calc);
$("#in2").keyup(calc);

function calc() {

    $('#result_in').html(
        parseFloat($('#in1').val(), 10) + parseFloat($("#in2").val(), 10 + parseFloat($("#in3").val(), 10)
    );
}
</script>

<script>
$(function ($) {

    $('body').on("click", '#addFieldsIn', function () {
        $('#table-in').append('<div class="tr"><div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div><div class="td2">1</div><div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in1" placeholder="0" value=""></div></div>')
    })

})(jQuery)
</script>
<div id="table-in">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1-title">In</div>
        <div class="td2-title">&#x25;</div>
        <div class="td3-title">&euro;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div>
        <div class="td2">1</div>
        <div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in1" placeholder="0" value=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div>
        <div class="td2">1</div>
        <div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in2" placeholder="0" value=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div>
        <div class="td2">1</div>
        <div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in3" placeholder="0" value=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tableEnd">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1"><button id="addFieldsIn">+ Add field</button></div>
        <div class="td2"></div>
        <div class="td3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td1-title">Total in</div>
        <div class="td2-title">1</div>
        <div class="td3-title" id="result_in"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**

## EDIT jQuery

I tried to combine multiple functions, but it breaks the calculations for `var totalIn`. What do I do wrong?

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  calc(); //call function to calculate
  $('body').on("click", '#addFieldsIn', function() {
    $('#table-in').append('<div class="tr"><div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description"></div><div class="td2">1</div><div class="td3"><input type="number" placeholder="0"></div></div>')
    calc(); //if passing any default value in input box 
  })
  
  $('body').on("click", '#addFieldsOut', function() {
    $('#table-out').append('<div class="tr"><div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description"></div><div class="td2">1</div><div class="td3"><input type="number" placeholder="0"></div></div>')
    calc(); //if passing any default value in input box 
  })

  $('body').on("keyup", '.td3 > input', function() {
    calc(); //when value keyup in input box
  })

  function calc() {
    var totalIn = 0; //for storing overall total
    $("#table-in .td3 > input").each(function() {
      totalIn += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
    })
    $('#result_in').text(totalIn);
  }
  
  function calc() {
    var totalOut = 0; //for storing overall total
    $("#table-out .td3 > input").each(function() {
      totalOut += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
    })
    $('#result_out').text(totalOut);
  }
})
</script>
```

**

Comment: Do you need PHP? Seems like you are just using that for math but JS can do math as well. Also it is unclear what you mean by "saving the numbers", save them where, database, server, on the browser?

Comment: Here's an example of how it looks [link](https://ibb.co/8DxSgrJ) It only should be saved in the browser. It's a form to calculate all the fields and it all should happen in the browser.

Comment: There's no question of how it looks.

Comment: Your submit button should go _inside_ the form

Comment: True, but then the problems with the form occur.

Comment: As user3783243 already pointed out there's no need for PHP, there's also no need for a form or a submit button. Use a regular `<button type="button"...` to do your calculations, save your input rows and values in localstorage if you need to persist them across browser sessions.

Comment: Or you could use AJAX to send them to the server for saving, without refreshing the page.

Comment: a few points to improve your code
if you aren't going to us a document loaded/ready event  (missing from the first script present in the second) then your scripts will execute at the point the parser hits them, this means you need to place them last in the documents to ensure all the element references have actually been created, plus you don't need a script for each function you can have all of the scripts in a single script tag this makes it much easier to read your code

Answer (score 0):

Override the default submit function with Javascript and manually post the form using Ajax

In the example I gave, I presumed you have the `form` an ID `<form id="theform">`

```
$("#theform").submit(function(e){
  // don't do the default action
  e.preventDefault();

  submitData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: '',
    data: submitData,
    success: function(data){
      // Show feedback that the form was saved submitted
    },
  });
});
```

---

### Edit

I feel like this issue went into a completely different direction Lol.

But this is for your most recent edit.
you can't have two functions with the same name, so break them up.

##### Basic example

```js
function calc_in() {
  var totalIn = 0; //for storing overall total
  $("#table-in .td3 > input").each(function() {
    totalIn += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
  })
  $('#result_in').text(totalIn);
};

function calc_out() {
  var totalOut = 0; //for storing overall total
  $("#table-out .td3 > input").each(function() {
    totalOut += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
  })
  $('#result_out').text(totalOut);
};
function calc(){
  calc_out();
  calc_in();
};
```

##### Somewhat Optimized version (2 instead of 1)

```js
function calc_table(targetTable, targetResult) {
  var total = 0; //for storing overall total
  $(targetTable).find('.td3 > input').each(function() {
    total += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
  })
  $(targetResult).text(total);
};

function calc(){
  $.each(['in', 'out'], function(i, t){ // t - for target
    calc_table($('#table-'+t), $('#result_'+t));
  });
};
```

But the rest seems to work, I tested it locally..
if your still having issues with **NaN** you could do: `(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val()));` as an alternative

---

and I'd recommend placing the functions right above `$(document).ready(` so that they're **Global** functions.

- You can call them manually in the Console (for testing)
- In general the function should be **above** where it's being called (this is for all languages, good habit to get into)

Comment: This works, but only when I fill in at least two fields. When I just fill in one field the form breaks. The form breaks also when I use `<button id="addFieldsOut">+ Add field</button>`

Comment: I've Edited my answer. Basically: functions can't have the same name (else they overwrite each other!) ....Very odd the form tho.. but, like you, I normally end up not using `form` tags cause they don't work correctly for more complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your *.tr* then inside div get the value of input box and on each iteration add the sum of the value in any variable and assign it to your *result_in* div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  calc(); //call fnction to calculate
  $('body').on("click", '#addFieldsIn', function() {
    $('#table-in').append('<div class="tr"><div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div><div class="td2">1</div><div class="td3"><input type="number" placeholder="0" value=""></div></div>')
    calc(); //if passing any default value in input box 
  })

  $('body').on("change", '.td3 > input', function() {
    calc(); //when value change in input box
  })

  function calc() {
    var total = 0; //for storing overall total
    $("#table-in .td3 > input").each(function() {
      total += ($(this).val()) ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0; //further can format to parsefloat if needed or add more checks
    })
    $('#result_in').text(total);
  }
})
```

```css
#table-in>.tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#result_in {
  color: red;
}

#table-in {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td1,
.td2,
.td3 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table-in">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td1">In</div>
    <div class="td2">&#x25;</div>
    <div class="td3">&euro;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div>
    <div class="td2">1</div>
    <div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in1" placeholder="0" value=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td1"><input type="text" placeholder="Change description" value=""></div>
    <div class="td2">1</div>
    <div class="td3"><input type="number" id="in3" placeholder="0" value=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <div class="td1">Total in</div>
  <div class="td2">1</div>
  <div class="td3" id="result_in"></div>
</div>
<div class="tr">
  <div class="td1"><button id="addFieldsIn">+ Add field</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work. I changed `$('body').on("change", '.td3 > input', function() {` to `$('body').on("keyup", '.td3 > input', function() {` and `total += ($(this).val()) ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;` to `total += ($(this).val()) ? parseFloat($(this).val()) : 0;`. Is that okay? I also have the same form for Table Out and a form to calculate. The overall results. How can I extend the jQuery with calculations for Table Out and Table Overall?

Comment: So I also need to add #addFieldsOut and calculate #table-out and #result_out

Comment: So, there are 2 table both have there individual calculation and also 3rd table for over all am i right ? @edow

Comment: Yes that is correct @Swati

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d23Lbt8k/) once @edow

Comment: Very nice! Works great! Last two questions: 1. How can I show more then once `id="result_in"` on the page? It seems I can use it only once. 2. Before I used `<?php $better_number_format_in = number_format($in1 + $in2, 2, ',', '.'); echo $better_number_format_in; ?>` to show a nice number format. Is this still possible? Again, thank you and when it's possible I give you +50 reputation.

Comment: Question 3: If you can also help me with calculating `<div class="td2">0</div>` then that would be awesome, but I can also open a new question for this. It seems out of my reach when it comes to coding. `<div class="td2">0</div>` has to show the percentage related to "Total in" and there also should be a total of percentages to calculate if it is 100% altogether. The same for "Total out". I understand if it's to much to ask, but I give it a try.

Comment: What do you mean by *show more then once* ? @edow . For question 3 you can create separate question with attempts you have done to achieve same.

Comment: I mean that I want to show the number (for example the number of “Total in”) on different places on the page. Ok, I’ll try. Thanks again.

Comment: just use`$('#result_in').text();` to get the value of total in and you can show in on any places

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. For now I added `$("#result_summary_in").html(parseFloat($('#result_in').text()))` into the bottom of the script and then used `id="result_summary_in"` into the HTML. Is that okay? I gave you the +50 reputation.

Comment: Can you gave me a hint where to begin to start calculating the percentage of every `<div class="td2"></div>` from `<div class="td3-title" id="result_in">0</div>` (also with "Total out") ?

Comment: same you can loop through td2 tag and get the sum and apply to your div @edow